# Shape.Copy Series.Paste, without touching clipboard

Tags: excel, vba, charts, clipboard

Behold minimal VBA code that successfully does one instance of using a shape as the marker for an Excel chart series.

```
Function TestFormatting(Optional ignoredParameter As Variant)
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Shapes("Shape1").Copy
        .ChartObjects("Chart1").Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Paste
    End With
End Function  ' TestFormatting
```

Alas, this code vandalises the clipboard. Please, do readers know of **any way to achieve this task without changing the clipboard?** My two candidate solutions have both failed.

1. Not damaging the clipboard by some sort of `.Copy Dest:=`. Happily that compiles; unhappily does not execute.
2. Some means of, with respect to the clipboard, that which a PostScript programmer might call `save … restore`. It might be possible to save the clipboard if I knew it contained just text (which I haven’t managed to make work), but anyway the clipboard might contain anything: perhaps small, perhaps big, perhaps not from Excel.

Aside, for those wondering why it is a function. So that the correct formatting of a chart can be part of Excel’s recalc sequence: if the name of a series changes, its formatting would correctly follow. The actual function would take some parameters including `ChartObject.Name` and `Series.Name`. The `ignoredParameter` might be something that would change if the desired formatting were to change, so triggering re-execution.

My target is that it work on most modern(ish) Excel versions, but anyway I’m using Mac Excel 16.43.

Comment: What do you mean by "vandalises the clipboard"?

Comment: Replaces contents of clipboard with the shape, per `Shape.Copy`. When copying a range from one place to another one can `Range1.Copy Dest:=Range2`, which doesn’t replace contents of the clipboard, so this type of problem has been acknowledged and fixed by Microsoft.

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong... Always using `.Copy` involves clipboard! Using `Range1.Copy Dest:=Range2` **jeopardizes the previous clipboard content and also clear clipboard after pasting**. You can easily test it using `Range_1.Copy` followed by  `Range1.Copy Dest:=Range2` and then using `Activesheet.Select: ActiveSheet.Paste`. According to your supposition, it should paste the `Range_1` content, but this is not happening...

Comment: Two errors of mine. `Destination`, not `Dest`. And I’m sure it used to not tamper with the clipboard, but today it does. Hmm. Mysteriouser and mysteriouser. And further from a solution.

Comment: Is the shape to be copied of `Image` type? Are there **already** the images you need to place on the chart, or **you can load them whenever you need to place them on the chart `SeriesCollection`**? If you can use new such images, I think I have a solution...

Comment: It is an SVG. Quite small: at most 824 bytes of SVG. If relevant, from this
https://www.askwoody.com/forums/topic/excel-and-svg/

Comment: The SVGs are in a Sheets.Shapes collection, almost always a different sheet to the one holding the chart. But if it were useful, say, to store them in a different way on that sheet — in a chart on that sheet — then that could be done. But they will not usually be in the same chart as the one being formatted.

Comment: You need to use `ActiveX` Image controls, but they do not support `svg` pictures. You can convert `svg` to `jpg` online easily. If convenient, I can show you how to save the image and load it on the chart `SeriesCollection` without needing clipboard. Or, even better, loading `SVG` on chart `SeriesCollection` directly from a computer path, not needing the embedded pictures on the sheet(s)... Using their name to differentiate the using cases.

Comment: This is part of an open-source project aimed at a large audience, many of whom will be security conscious. I can’t assume ActiveX. But these questions and answers live forever: please post it anyway. (SVG➝︎bitmap is easy: I have tools.)

Comment: Wouldn't it be more convenient to load the `SVG` files directly from the computer path? According to their name...

Comment: Actually, no, because that assumes access permissions. But please show the answer anyway.

Comment: But, the access permissions are necessary, anyhow,  to "save - restore", at least, for a specific location...

Comment: Please, test the pieces of code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next ways:

1. Load `SVG` file from computer path:

```
Sub ApplySVGPictOnSeriesCollection()
   Dim ch As ChartObject, rng As Range
   
   Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("I2:J4") 'place here the SourceData
   
   Set ch = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(left:=1, top:=1, width:=100, height:=100)
   ch.Chart.SetSourceData rng
   
   With ch.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Fill
        .UserPicture PictureFile:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\sample_640×426.svg" 'use here your svg file path
        .Visible = True
   End With
End Sub
```

2. Convert the `SVG` files to `bmp` or (`jpg`, `gif`, `Wmf`, `emf`) then, insert sheet `ActiveX` `Image` controls and place the pictures in the above format on them. They can be used as in the next piece of code:

```
Sub copyPictureToSeriesCollectionNoClipboard()
    Dim s As Shape, ch As ChartObject, rng As Range, img As Image
    
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("I2:J4")
    
    Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Image1") 'an ActiveX Image control shape 
    
    Set img = s.OLEFormat.Object.Object 'image
    stdole.SavePicture img.Picture, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\myPicture123.jpg"
      
   'create a new chart:
   Set ch = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(left:=1, top:=1, width:=100, height:=100)
   
   ch.Chart.SetSourceData rng
   
   With ch.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Fill 'place the pictures:
        .UserPicture PictureFile:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\myPicture123.jpg"
        .Visible = True
   End With
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing them.

Comment: Marked as the correct answer, though actually much longer than needed. It suffices for me to have the SVG files locally, read-only, for which `.UserPicture PictureFile:=…` does the necessary work. Thank you.

Comment: @jdaw1 But, if I remember well, **I** suggested this approach...  The second pieces of code only tries following you question request, but using a shape offering the possibility to save the picture. For the case of **transporting** the pictures embedded in the workbook. Then, it is not mandatory to have the SVG file saved locally, they can be saved on the network, too.